# AzureML custom environment not recognizing CUDA

Tags: azure

I am trying to create a custom environment and use that for a gpu cluster but the GPUs are not being recognized.  Here's a minimal example.  Conda environment file `py310gpu.yml`

```
name: py310gpu
channels:
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/
dependencies:
  - python>=3.10.10
  - pip>=23.0
  - pytorch>=1.12.1
  - tensorboard>=2.12.2
  - pip:
    - --index-url https://pypi.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.org
    - azureml-core>=1.5.0
    - azure-ai-ml>=1.5.0
```

Registered using the following code as a custom environment

```
from azureml.core import Environment, Workspace

ws = Workspace.from_config()
env = Environment("py310gpu").from_conda_specification(name="py310gpu", file_path="./py310gpu.yml")
env.docker.base_image = "mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-cuda11.6-cudnn8-ubuntu20.04"
env.register(workspace=ws)
```

I can see it in the portal and when I hit `Build` it builds just fine.

Here's a `hello_cuda.py` example.

```
import torch

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(f"using device {device}")

if device.type == "cuda":
  print(f"device name {torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)}")
```

Used the following code to run on a compute cluster (Standard_NC6s_v3).

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient, command
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

ws = Workspace.from_config()
args_ws = dict(subscription_id=ws.subscription_id, resource_group_name=ws.resource_group, workspace_name=ws._workspace_name)
ml_client = MLClient(credential=DefaultAzureCredential(), **args_ws, enable_telemetry=False)

job = command (inputs=None, code=".", command="python hello_cuda.py",
  environment="py310gpu:7", compute="vn-nc6sv3-i0", experiment_name="vn-gpu-test"
)
status = ml_client.create_or_update(job)
```

The output is

```
using device cpu
```

Just to test, I fired up a similar Compute Instance, built an environment using the conda file above, and ran the hello script to get the following output

```
using device cuda
device name Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB
```

Any idea what I need to change?  I also tried with `cuda11.3` base image and that does not help either.